# JSF - How to reset the <ice:dataTable> value list

Tags: jsf, icefaces

Couple of days ago I started JSF with Iceface. I have a dataTable and when I delete a row,
It deletes the particular list entry from the back-end. Also dataTable remove a row, but not the one I deleted. 
(It is not about the complete row. Its only a column.)
I'm using a suggestion box for each row. Problem only happens with that suggestion box field. But without that suggestion box, it works fine.

I thought if I could refresh/sync again the dataTable with it's bean property, just before rendering it, might solve the problem.
(From back-end it maintains the exact data set that I want to populate in my dataTable.)

At the moment what I want to know is, how can we re-sync the dataTable with it's new value, before render the response.

If you have any other idea please share it with me.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. When a question is closed, nobody can't answer it. The best option will be to move your *update* section into an answer, remove the *update* section from your question and accept your own answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a mistake :(
I haven't add the `value="#{o.itemId}"` property.
This is my suggestion box.
Thanks!

```
<ice:selectInputText id="sugestBox" rows="10" width="290"
    listVar="item"
    valueChangeListener="#{o.itemAutoCompleteBean.updateList}"
    actionListener="#{o.lst}"
    listValue="#{o.itemAutoCompleteBean.matchesList}"
    value="#{o.itemId}">

<f:facet name="selectInputText">
    <ice:panelGrid columns="3" style="margin-bottom:20px; "
                columnClasses="sgstItemDropCol,sgstItemDescCol,sgstItemCatCol" >
        <ice:outputText value="#{item.itemId}"/>
        <ice:outputText value="#{item.description}"/>
        <ice:outputText value="#{item.category}"/>
    </ice:panelGrid>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: What is "o" ? Name variables properly.

Comment: @r0ast3d: This suggestion box resides inside a dataTable. So "o" represents the object for a particular row.